# Interfacing Figaro KE25 Oxygen Gas Sensor with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been trying to interface the **Figaro KE25 2 lead fuel cell type oxygen gas sensor** with **Arduino Uno**. I am not getting the required output on the Serial Monitor for regular air (Oxygen concentration of 19%).

I have attached the **sketch** I have typed out, the **output I have obtained on the Serial Monitor**, the **output(mV) vs Oxygen concentration (%) graph** of the Figaro KE25 sensor I have obtained from the datasheet, the **chemical reactions governing the working of the sensor**,the **circuit diagram** I have used, and the **construction of the sensor**.

In this question; I will explain the sensor first, then my circuit, then my sketch, and lastly the problem I have with my output.

In **electronics**, the **Anode is the positive electrode** and the **cathode is the negative** electrode. In ***electrochemistry***, the ***Anode is the Negative electrode*** and the ***Cathode is the positive electrode***. Do check the image of the construction of the sensor I have provided obtained from the datasheet.[![image of the construction of the sensor][1]][1] [Full Technical Datasheet](http://www.meditronik.com.pl/doc/b0-b9999/ke25.pdf)

The **Cathode**, that is, **the positive electrode** is the **sensing electrode** (Oxygen gets consumed here and an electric current is generated). Since a current is being generated by the sensor (fuel cell), **no power supply needs to be given to the sensor**. Check the image of the chemical reactions provided (obtained from the full technical datasheet of the sensor). [image: Chemical Reactions][Technical Datasheet](http://www.figarosensor.com/products/entry/ke-25.html#ti)

The sensor in question is an analog voltage type sensor. Keeping this and everything I have mentioned above in mind, I have constructed the following circuit with Arduino Uno. Refer the picture I have put up. I have connected the **Cathode (the sensing positive electrode, red in colour) to the Arduino's analog A0 pin** and **the Anode (negative electrode) to the Arduino's ground**. [image: Circuit]

The sketch I have used is as follows:

```
 /*the analog pin of the alcohol sensor goes into analog pin A0 of the  
 Arduino*/

 void setup()
 {
     Serial.begin(9600); //sets the baud rate
 }

 void loop()
 {
     float v1;
     float oxy = 0.0;
     float v2 = 0.0;
     pinMode(A0,INPUT_PULLUP);

     /*To make sure that reading is zero when the circuit is open*/

     v1 = analogRead(A0); 

     /*reads the analog value from the Oxygen gas sensor and this value can
     be anywhere from 0 to 1023 (10 bit ADC used in Arduino Uno)*/ 

     if(v1>900) //To make sure that reading is zero when the circuit is open
     {
         v1=0;
     }
     v2 = (v1*3000)/992; 

     /*The above line calculates the output of the sensor in mV using the
     fact that a HIGH reading in an input pin of an Arduino Uno board is
     equivalent to a voltage of 3V or higher. When I displayed just 'v1',
     the lowest of the high values I got was 992. So I equated it to 3V
     (3000mV) and used the unitary method to find out what a non-HIGH v1 
     value would be in terms of mV.*/

     oxy = v2/0.6; 

     /*The above line calculates the Oxygen concentration from the mV output 
     of the sensor using the output(mV) vs concentration(%) graph from the 
     sensor's datasheet. The graph is a straight line passing through (0,0) 
     and hence the governing equation is of the form y = m * x. Where 'y' is 
     'v2' and 'x' is Oxygen conc. in %.*/

     Serial.print("Oxygen value: ");
     Serial.print(v1);
     Serial.print("    ");
     Serial.print(v2);
     Serial.print("mV    ");
     Serial.print(oxy);//prints the Oxygen value
     Serial.println("%");

     delay(1000);
 }
```

he output(mV) vs Oxygen concentration(%) graph provided in the datasheet is shown below. The straight line labeled as 'KE25' is to be considered. [image: O/P(mV) vs. O2 conc.(%)] [Product information (datasheet)](http://www.figarosensor.com/products/docs/KE%20Prod%20Info%20%281014%29.pdf)

he output I have obtained on the serial monitor is as follows:
[image: SerialMonitor]

Such a high voltage from the sensor is not possible. My output reading is not possible at all. Where have I made a mistake and how do I correct it?

> **Update 1 :** I changed the line `pinMode(A0,INPUT_PULLUP)` to `pinMode(A0,INPUT)`. Now I am getting sensible values on my Serial Monitor. However, I am also getting many '0' outputs **(many)**. I am also getting many random values **(many)**. I need more information on how to interface a fuel cell type Oxygen sensor using Arduino Uno in terms of how to get a proper voltage reading across such a sensor. I have found no question on electrochemical, fuel cell type Oxygen gas sensor interfacing. All questions asked are regarding sensors that require a power supply. In case of fuel cell type Oxygen gas sensors, current is generated when Oxygen is sensed and hence, no power supply is required. Also, if anyone is into electrochemistry, how do I check the voltage output of a fuel cell type Oxygen gas sensor using a voltmeter? Do I use a DC voltmeter or an AC voltmeter?
>
> **Update 2:** I've made changes to the code based on @EdgarB's suggestions. The output I am getting now is better but still wrong. I checked if the sensors I am using are functional using a multimeter (I confirmed if the method I am using is right, and it is), and they are. The Oxygen values I am getting now are still really low: 6-8%. I should be getting: 19-21%. I used a reference voltage of 600 mV and modified the code.
>
> Modified code:

```
 void setup()

 {

     Serial.begin(9600);//sets the baud rate
     analogReference(INTERNAL);
 }

 void loop()
 {
     const float A_REF = 0.6e3;
     const float Scalc = (1/0.6);

     float v1;
     float oxy = 0.0;
     float v2 = 0.0;
     pinMode(A0, INPUT); 
     v1 = analogRead(A0);
     v2 = (v1 * A_REF) / 1024;
     oxy = v2 * Scalc;
     Serial.print("Oxygen value: ");
     Serial.print(v1);
     Serial.print("    ");
     Serial.print(v2,4);
     Serial.print("mV    ");
     Serial.print(oxy,4);//prints the Oxygen value
     Serial.println("%");
     delay(1000);
 }
```

> Output:
>   [image: Output]

Comment: If you remove the `pinMode(A0,INPUT_PULLUP);` does it improve the readings?

Comment: Read this page: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins - Especially the bit entitled "Pull-up resistors".

Comment: @Majenko Thanks! That really helped. I changed `pinMode(A0,INPUT_PULLUP);` to `pinMode(A0,INPUT);`I had read that page before typing out my sketch, but I didn't pay much attention to the line that said: "Be aware however that turning on a pull-up will affect the values reported by analogRead()." Is this because in a short time interval like 1000 ms there isn't enough time for the voltage to drop to low and then rise again to the correct input given from the sensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from having the internal pullup resistor for A0 turned on.

The sensor is a current generator with a load resistor (plus thermistor) built in to convert the current into a voltage. By adding a pullup resistor you turn it into a voltage divider across 5V with a small current being injected into the central node:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzCEPV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since the datasheet doesn't specify the load resistance nor the source current I have made up some values to demonstrate.

If we take just the current source and load resistance RL+RT and calculate the voltage drop across that we get:

```
V=R×I = 5000 × 0.00001 = 50mV
```

Which is a reasonable value. It's a lot of oxygen, but that's because these are made-up values.

Now what would be the voltage with the pullup resistor added? Well, this is where it gets a little more complex. At times like this it's easier to just simulate the circuit in something like the [falstad simulator](http://tinyurl.com/yalptakx) and I can tell you it's **757.1mV** (If you want to learn how to do this kind of circuit analysis manually you should learn [superposition theory](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/superposition-theorem/)).

A massive change.

Obviously you're not seeing a change *that* big - and that's because the pullup resistor is *more* than just a simple resistor. There's many more factors that influence the reading, including the output impedance of the network, as well as the rest of the internal ADC circuitry.

Suffice it to say, though, adding a pullup resistor is a bad idea when using the ADC.

But you want to keep the pullup resistor so you can know if the sensor is connected or not. That's not a problem. Just turn it on and off at will:

```
pinMode(A0, INPUT_PULLUP);
delay(1);
bool connected = analogRead(A0) < 900;
if (connected) {
    pinMode(A0, INPUT);
    delay(1);
    v1 = analogRead(A0);
}
```

It's recommended to wait a moment after changing the pullup resistor state before reading from the ADC to reduce electrical noise picked up by the ADC - hence the `delay(1)` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You calculation of v2 is incorrect.

```
v2 = (v1 * 3000) / 992;
```

The maximum value v1 will have is 1023 and this equates to 5v (not 3v).  So to calculate the voltage v2 I think you should be doing:

```
v2 = (v1 / 1023) * 5000;
```

But this will make your calculations even further out!

Comment: The maximum voltage at a pin that is configured as OUTPUT is 5V in a 5V Arduino Uno board. However, on the same board, if a pin is configured as INPUT, then the voltage at the pin is 3V or higher. Check [https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/constants/constants/]

Comment: I was just reading what analogInput() said.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different issues here:

1. improper use of the pullup resistor
2. incorrect interpretation of the analog reading
3. too small input signal

### Pullup resistor

Majenko already covered the first issue, with very good advice.

### Interpretation of the analog reading

Code Gorilla already explained the second issue. However, since you do
not seem to understand, I will add my take here.

The formula to convert an analog reading to an actual voltage is

voltage = reading × analog_reference ÷ 1024.

Yes, it's 1024 rather the often seen (but erroneous) 1023. See [the
manufacturer's datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf), which is the *only* authoritative
reference. Doesn't make much of a difference anyway. The main issue is
the analog reference voltage which, in the default configuration, is the
same as the voltage powering the Arduino, i.e. 5 V.

In a comment, you wrote:

> if a pin is configured as INPUT, then the voltage at the pin is 3V or
>   higher

This is complete nonsense. The voltage on an input pin is whatever
voltage is provided by the circuit connected to that pin. If you
actually mean the *threshold voltage* for the pin reading `HIGH`, well,
that threshold is typically 2.6 V (see the “typical
characteristics” in the datasheet), but the exact value is not
guaranteed. The number you quote is “the lowest value where the pin is
guaranteed to be read as high”. In other words, the voltage threshold
can be lower than 3 V, but not higher.

And all this is completely irrelevant to you. The input thresholds are a
feature of the digital input circuitry attached to the pin. This circuit
is responsible for deciding whether the pin is `LOW` or `HIGH` when you
`digitalRead()` it. But you don't care about the digital value: you are
using the pin as an analog input. The ADC converter is a different
circuitry that has *absolutely nothing to do* with the digital input.
You can even disable the digital input of the pin and still use the ADC.

### Low signal

According to the graph you provide, the sensor should output
12.6 mV in normal air (21% O<sub>2</sub>). That's about
2.58 ADC steps. Thus you expect the reading to fluctuate between
the digital values 2 and 3. This is really quite low for your ADC.

A simple way to mitigate this problem is to change the analog reference.
The default is 5 V, but [you can switch it to an internal
1.1 V reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/) that will significantly increase
your resolution: in `setup()`, call

```c++
analogReference(INTERNAL);
```

Then you can compute the oxygen level as follows:

```c++
const float A_REF = 1.1e3;         // analog reference = 1,100 mV
const float SENSOR_CAL = 1 / 0.6;  // calibration: %(O2) / mV

void loop()
{
    int reading = analogRead(A0);
    float voltage = reading * (A_REF / 1024);
    float oxygen = voltage * SENSOR_CAL;
    // ...
}
```

Another way to mitigate the signal weakness is to average multiple
readings. This can make your effective resolution better than the raw
ADC resolution.

### ADC offset

The formula

voltage = reading × analog_reference ÷ 1024

applies only to an ideal ADC. In practice, any ADC has some offset error
and gain error. Taking them into account, the formula becomes:

voltage = (reading + offset_error) × analog_reference ÷ (1024 + gain_error)

In many cases these errors are too small to care about. However, since
you are working near the resolution limit of your ADC, the offset error
can be an important concern. The gain error is no issue here, so you can
forget about it.

If you have a voltmeter, you can easily determine the offset error:
measure a low voltage, like the one from your sensor, with both the
voltmeter and the ADC. Ideally, you would average many ADC readings to
get a better resolution. From the voltmeter measurement, you compute the
average reading you would expect from your ADC, then you get

offset_error = expected_ADC_reading − actual_ADC_reading

Then you use this measured offset to correct your readings:

```c++
const float offset_error = ...;  // measured with the voltmeter

void loop()
{
    int reading = analogRead(A0);
    float voltage = (reading + offset_error) * (A_REF / 1024);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I meant that if a pin is configured as INPUT and is at HIGH then the voltage at that pin is 3V or higher. I will read the rest of your answer and update on  the status soon.

Comment: @athindrapavan: Understood what you mean, but: 1. It's wrong (a pin can read `HIGH` even at 2.2 V) 2. It's irrelevant to an analog reading.

Comment: First of all, thanks! That helped in getting a better, more precise output. Plus, I understand the assignable constants better now. But I'm still getting a wrong output in terms of the range of Oxygen percentage values I should be getting. I'm getting around 6-8% of Oxygen which is still too low. It has to be 19-21% in regular air. I checked if the sensors I am using are functional with a multimeter and they are. I'll update the question with the modified code and the output I am getting in some time. Please do check it.

Comment: @athindrapavan: 1. The internal analog reference is 1.1 V, not 600 mV. You cannot just make up a number and expect that to work. 2. You may also suffer from ADC offset error. See the amended answer.

Comment: @ EdgarB Your answer made a lot of sense and the setup is working now. Is the offset error value sensor dependent? That is if I use 2 new Figaro KE-25 sensors, then will it cause an error in one of the 2 sensors depending on which one I used to calculate the offset error?

Comment: @athindrapavan: No, the offset error is intrinsic to the ADC. It should not depend on the sensor. It may depend though on whether you are using `analogReference(DEFAULT)` (i.e. Vcc) `analogReference(INTERNAL)` (i.e. 1.1 V).

Comment: So since I've used the latter, it's intrinsic to the ADC? Also, thanks a ton! Your answer was very detailed and a lot of help.